# Loop with Image Magick in batch file

Tags: batch, imagemagick

I'm trying to loop through a folder to convert SVG files to PNG files using Image Magick in a batch file:

I am wanting to put the new PNG files into a new folder.

This is what I have:

```
for /r %%f in ("C:\Users\tatte\Desktop\SVG") do (
SET filename = %~nxf
magick "C:/Users/tatte/Desktop/SVG/%filename%" "C:/Users/tatte/Desktop/TV/%filename%.png"
)
```

The files in the SVG folder are not converted and are not in the TV folder.

Comment: Have you considered using *backslashes* in your command instead?

Comment: @QuickishFM, the `magick` command uses forward slashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code/syntax contains some errors:

```py
for /Recursevelly %%f in "C:\Users\tatte\Desktop\SVG") do...
SET filename|⇄|=|⇄|%~nxf  
magick "C:/Users/tatte/Desktop/SVG/Name From /R File in Subfolder" ^
                "C:/Users/tatte/Desktop/TV/Set var = using space+single % .png"
```

1. You are using a wrong recursive `for` loop and without pointing out which files you want to use in loop process
2. Use `set` without space `before=` and `=after` the equal sign, and using `%%` instead `%`
3. This is a fixed path `"C:/Users/tatte/Desktop/SVG/%filename%"` using a variable `%filename%` that has a recursive origin (besides being wrongly defined), where the name may belong to a file in a subfolder, and would not be found at the level pointed out fixed.

---

1. Maybe you can try using `For /F` instead `For /R` with `Where /R`
2. Replace/removing `set filename = %%i` by using %% i variable in loop itself

```py
@echo off 

Set "_Yours_Files=%userprofile%\Desktop\SVG"
Set "_ImageMagick=C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.10-Q16-HDRI"

for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('%__APPDIR__%where.exe /r "%_Yours_Files%" *.svg"
')do "%_ImageMagick%\magick.exe" "%%i" "%userprofile%\Desktop\TV\%%~ni.png"
```

The `For /F` loop with `Where /R` (recursively) will find your all svg file (`*.svg`) and pass the full path as an argument to ImageMagick

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[For /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**

  [√] **[Where](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html)**

  [√] **[Where sample](https://www.petri.com/using-where-exe)**